# error wrong sign in 'by' argument while using grid.expand function in kriging (R)

Tags: r, coordinates, latitude-longitude, kriging

I am building kriging model in R. I have plotted Lat Longs of city.With the help of locator function I have figured out boundries of city. Now I want to expand this thing which I can do using grid.expand fuction in which we do have "by" argument in which we can mention figure in meters. But i am getting error which running this line,

[referring this site for coding](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/46259_d328295794034414944deea60552a942.html)

```
rd <- read.csv("Test.csv")
coordinates(rd) = ~Long+Lat
plot(rd)
locator(4)
x.range <- as.integer(c(72.74158,73.01315))
y.range <- as.integer(c(19.23944,18.88680))
grd <- expand.grid(
  x=seq(from=x.range[1], to=x.range[2], by=200),
  y=seq(from=y.range[1], to=y.range[2], by=200)
)
coordinates(grd) <- ~ x+y
gridded(grd) <- TRUE
```

Comment: That's the error you get in `seq()` if `from` is smaller than `to`, or in your case, because `y.range[1]` is smaller than `y.range[2]`, then you'd need a negative `by`. In both cases, this looks wrong, using `by=200` with such small values you'll always have a sequence of length 1.

Comment: Yeah there was issue in y as you have mentioned. Thank you for your help.